# How to specify table schema in spring-data-jdbc

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

In my project, I use spring-data-jdbc version 2.0.4.RELEASE and I'm stuck with the problem of how to specify a schema for a table. The entity class looks like this

```java
@Data
@Table(value = "alpha.op_organization")
public class OrganizationEntity {
   @Id
   private Long id;
   @Column(name="name")
   private String name;
}
```

If I try to save entity with jdbc repository method `save` like this

```java
OrganizationEntity organization = new OrganizationEntity();
organization.setName("OrgName1");
organizationRepository.save(organisation)
```

I have got exception "Releation alpha.op_organization does not exist. Corresponding sql query is

```sql
INSERT INTO "alpha.op_organization" ("name") VALUES (?)
```

I. e. it turns out that we are trying to insert an entry in the table "alpha.op_organization" and not in the table op_organization in the schema alpha.

I tred to customize NamingStrategy to return schema alpha but with no luck.

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration {
   @Bean
   public NamingStrategy namingStrategy() {
      return new NamingStrategy() {

         @Override
         public String getSchema() {
            return "alpha";
         }
      };
   }
}
```

Is there any way to specify the table schema in spring-data-jdbc?

Answer (score 3):

if you are using

```
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;
```

Spring trying build query

> INSERT INTO "alpha.op_organization" ("name") VALUES (?)

but we need

> INSERT INTO "alpha"."op_organization" ("name") VALUES (?)

try:

```
@Table(value = "alpha\".\"op_organization")
```

Comment: This worked for me. Also keep in mind that the schema and table name are case sensitive with the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the way to do this is to define a `NamingStrategy`. Example taken from [this integration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/blob/master/spring-data-jdbc/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jdbc/core/JdbcAggregateTemplateSchemaIntegrationTests.java) test:

```
@Bean
NamingStrategy namingStrategy() {
    return new NamingStrategy() {
        @Override
        public String getSchema() {
            return "other";
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This solution works for me only if entity class does not annotated with "@Table" annotation. If class it does, my custom NamingStrategy does not call. Can you explain me how to set schema with namingstrategy and "@Table" annotation, please?

Answer (score 0):

I use postgresql + HikariDataSource.
So in my case:

```
 @Bean
 public DataSource dataSource() {

        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
...
        if(schema != null && !schema.isEmpty()){
            hikariConfig.setConnectionInitSql("SET SEARCH_PATH TO " + schema);
        }
        
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
        return dataSource;
  }
```

And entity annotated like this:
@Table("user")
correct mapped into service.user

Answer (score 0):

Assign `currentSchema` parameter in the JDBC connection url.

Example: `jdbc:postgresql://server/catalog?currentSchema=schema`

This gave me more flexible in terms of different table name but no need to describe the same schema name again in the `@Table` annotation.

[Postgres JDBC connections documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters)

Comment: It seems that this solution does not work if tables in different schemas

Comment: @MadMax You have to add `@Table("another_schema.table_name")` annotation for the specific `Entity` which has different schema. 
For those `Entity` which has different table name but same schema then no need to explicitly specify the schema again in the `@Table` annotation but just with the table name only, like this `@Table("different_table_name")`.

Comment: Actualy i have tried this possibility but with no luck. It seams that jdbc or someone else perceives it as table name "another_schema.table_name" (like single undivided table name). I think so because i got exception from undelying db driver 'Relation "another_schema.table_name" does not exist'. But this releation does exists, of course.

Comment: @MadMax That seems odd, on my end it's working and I used Postgres and Spring Data JDBC 2.1.5 with Spring Boot 2.4.3.

Comment: thx, i will try to use this versions of jdbc. May be it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being kind of late, but I think I can help other developers here. As @MadMax mentioned, specifying `NamingStrategy#getSchema()` does not really work with `@Table`. In fact, [there is bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/issues/1099), and it is reported in spring-data-jdbc,
that actually tells that specifying `@Table#value` is not working together with `NamingStrategy`.

The good news is that there is a [Pull Request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/pull/1108) opened in spring-data-jdbc in order to solve this issue. The changes, introduced by this  Pull Request will add `schema` parameter to `@Table` annotation, which will allow you to explicitly specify the schema for each table, if you prefer to do so. Also this PR will eliminate this bug.

**What can you do for now** : well, if you are unfortunate enough and you need to use `@Table#value` in conjunction with `NamingStrategy#getSchema()` - it wont work. If you really need to specify the schema, you need to get rid of `@Table` annotation for now. If you will do so, the schema from NamingStrategy will apply properly.

Answer (score 0):

One can override schema directly in DataSource:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {
    @Autowired
    public void configureDataSource(HikariDataSource dataSource) {
        dataSource.setSchema("SCHEMA_NAME");
    }
}
```

or simply specify in `application.yml`

```
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      schema: 'SCHEMA_NAME'
```